# Why would this code not work y = window.scrollY;?

Tags: javascript, web, scroll

I am attempting to use the following code:

```
y = window.scrollY;
```

For some reason, on the particular website, I only get that y = 0 regardless of how far I scroll vertically. Is there any particular reason for this? It does work on other websites. The problem is not limited to browsers (tested on Chrome and Firefox).

Update: I found out that the reason for the issue is that the site is contained within a div with position set to relative. Is there any way around this without disrupting the content of the site?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?  Hard to tell what is happening without some context.

Comment: Are you constantly updating, or do you expect it to mirror `scrollY`? (Hint: it doesn't.)

Comment: Check the doctype -- I can't remember if the behavior/existence of `scrollY` changes based on strict vs quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say for sure but I bet they are using a div container that scrolls and not the "window".

```
y = document.getElementById("container").scrollY;
```